# Refresh Query Subform with new criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In a form I have an unbound textbox. I then have a subform in a tab control. The subform is a query as follows:

```
SELECT PCR.PCRnum AS PCR, STIA.STIARev AS Rev, STIA.WP, STIA.STIAPDF.FileName AS PDF
FROM PCR INNER JOIN STIA ON PCR.PCRnum = STIA.PCR
WHERE (PCR.PCRnum=FindPCR.PCRsearched);
```

I am trying to build a little VB code that will on exit of the textbox run the query in the subform matching the value with PCR.PCRnum

I am new to access VB (I do a lot of Excel VB) and I am having troubles with the references.

Thank you!

Comment: use textbox LostFocus  event it will fire when you exit the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need code if you use the LinkMasterFields and LinkChildFields properties of the subform control. In Design mode of your form, click once on the subform control. Look at the Properties list (F4). On the data tab try setting LinkMasterFields to `PCRsearched` and LinkChildFields to `PCR`. You might want to set FilterOnEmptyMaster to `No` if you want all records to show when your unbound textbox is empty. In any case, the subform will be refiltered whenever there is a change to the unbound text box.